# How can I send data over a web server for a commercial application?

Tags: java, android, mobile, webserver

I am currently working on an app I would soon like to release to the Google Play Store for Android devices. It involves the sending and receiving of data (in my case, they would be numerical values like GPS coordinates) between devices. My idea is: two users would create their own accounts, and then link those accounts, so that one of the respective devices would be the transmitter, and the other the receiver.

To accomplish this, I figured I would send the data to a web server. For instance, Device 1 transmits to the web server, and then the web server sends that data to Device 2.  My question is, since this would be a commercial application with many users, what kind of service should I use?

I have looked at other questions regarding this topic, but none of them deal with a commercial scale, where multiple clients are involved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your work faster without having to create your own web service, you can use Google's [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?gclid=Cj0KEQiAt9vEBRDQmPSow-q5gs8BEiQAaWSEDsrKJreQJAarQoIh8SkScdJSo0ays9SwsH6TTFFz_RkaAp8F8P8HAQ)

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution will work, because I want to display the data within the UI of the app. Thank you though.

Comment: Hi Jamie, You'll just use firebase messaging to send/receive data from other devices.After receiving the data, you can display it within your app's UI.